# iOS: Core data and disk space

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Does anyone know what happens if you try to save to core data, but there is not enough disk space left?

I'm assuming the save operation generates an NSError of some kind? How would you tell it was a disk space error not some other error during disk write?

Answer (score 9):

After a few hours of trying to fill up the disk, I've found that the error you get is:

```
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 13;
NSUnderlyingException = "error during SQL execution : database or disk is full";
```

It is rather difficult to get this error:

- iOS devices claim to be full before they really are.  I managed to squeeze an extra 206MB onto an iPod that claimed to have 0 bytes free.
- As the device fills up, it automatically starts deleting caches and other temporary files.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a poor choice by the CoreData developers when implementing their Error handling API.  instead of defining a NSCoreDataErrorDomain they're overloading NSCocoaErrorDomain and passing up SQLite error codes defined [here.](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the error by querying the NSError instance and parsing the result for the error domain involved. One of these domains probably has the error code you are looking for:

```
// Predefined domain for errors from most AppKit and Foundation APIs.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const NSCocoaErrorDomain;

// Other predefined domains; value of "code" will correspond to preexisting values in these domains.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const NSOSStatusErrorDomain;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const NSMachErrorDomain;
```

Comment: Right, I know you can query for the error code. I was mainly asking if someone might know or have encountered this before as you can't really test this on the simulator, and have to fill up an actual device to the point where you know the next core data saves will go over disk space.

Comment: nsx241, the leading error codes you are likely to receive are: `NSPersistentStoreSaveError`, `NSPersistentStoreIncompleteSaveError` or `NSSQLiteError`. Of course, if you want to prove this, you do have to fill up a device. A sample app to do so with large images is rater simple to write. Andrew